# MySQL 10:34:50 Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, key

I've seen many examples of how to fix this issue "Make sure that the foreign key matches the value of your primary key". But it still doesn't solve my problem

```
CREATE TABLE `order table`(
OrderId INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
`Product one` VARCHAR(60),
`Product two` VARCHAR(60),
`Product three` VARCHAR(60),
CustomerId INT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (CustomerId) REFERENCES customers(CustomerId)
);

INSERT INTO `new_schema`.`order table`(
OrderId, `Product one`, `Product two`, `Product three`, CustomerId)
VALUES ('0', 'Ryzen 7 3700xt',' Power Supply', 'Stuff', 0);
```

And yes, in my customer table there is a customer id with an int of 0, no typos as far as I'm concerned

Comment: If your table has only one FK and the error tells you that the FK constraint has failed, it would seem relatively straight-forward understanding what the issue is.  Despite the assertion to the contrary, a row in `customers` with `CustomerId = 0` cannot exist

Comment: The only other area to consider are triggers that may carry out additional processing that causing a FK issue but given that `order table` is freshly made, that seems unlikely

Comment: But it does exist. When creating a customer table, there is no issue inserting the primary key to be 0. It's in the table

Comment: I just figured out what was the issue. I was looking for a foreign key in `order table`, before I added data to the `customers` even though customers is the first table, data to it is added later. Dumb mistake to make, thanks for the help though

Comment: Glad to hear it's resolved.  The error message was correct in that case and the customer did not exist at the time you ran the code